# Elasticsearch time in Dataview

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, time

I am indexing data to an Elasticsearch cluster. In one index I defined a field called "duration", which represents a time-delta value, in the format of "HH:mm:ss".

Mappings:

```
{
...
"duration": {
   "type": "date",
   "format": "HH:mm:ss"
}
...
}
```

The data I post:

```
{"duration": "00:01:20"} //one minute and twenty secs
```

I successfully posted this data to Elasticsearch. But when I created DataView and visualized them with Kibana, the value of "duration" was converted into "**1 Jan 1970 00:01:20**", which is not friendly for time-delta view. I want it just be "**00:01:20**" like how I post.

What should I do now? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to go to `Stack Management` > `Advanced Settings` > `Date format` to change the default format to your desired one, e.g. HH:mm:ss

[image]